# can one port listen for two different protocols?

Tags: http, https, protocols, port

Hi
can the same port be used to listen to two different protocol request.. i.e.. can I use the same port for both http and https requests??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only do this if all of the protocols require the client to send data first.  You can write a pseudo-server to read data and detect the protocol in use and redirect it to the appropriate local server.  With protocols like ssh, this cannot be done since the server sends data first and the client responds to it.

Comment: thanks a lot howie. I am creating a mobile client which sends data , but many a times it responds only.. then it cannot be done?

Comment: @garima: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @howie my client responds to the data being sent by the server.

Answer (score 3):

You could, but you'd have to write your own listener on that port that could handle both situations.  There are no web servers I know of that can do it.

Answer (score 1):

For example socket.io over NodeJS does exactly that. It can listen to the standard port 80 and make decision over HTTP or WebSocket protocol usage.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic in fact serves two different protocols , http and LDAP, from the same port. 
Weblogic has an LDAP server embedded within it and both Weblogic server and the embedded LDAP server listen on the same port 7001.

You can access WL Admin console pointing you browser to http://earth1.com:7001/console

You can connect to the LDAP server through LDAP browser  ldap://earth1.coom:7001